# Problem with "." and "," characters. (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, keyboard-events

When playing game, characters `,` and `.` on the keyboard are switching the frames just like in Flash Professional CS5. I want to disable this ability to be able to track keyboard events including these two symbols. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as `.` and `,` are used by the built-in Flash Player to *Step Forward One Frame* and *Step Backward One Frame*, if you want your application to have access to these keys you have to *Disable Keyboard Shortcuts* when testing your application.

> Control > Disable Keyboard Shortcuts

[image]

Comment: oh, i found this button... but will these shortcuts be disabled in .exe i'm going to export? :S

Comment: it's the same on windows.  the `Disable Keyboard Shortcuts` menu item is only present in the `Control` menu while you are testing your movie.

Comment: will these shortcuts be disabled in .exe i'm going to export? :S

Comment: .swf files and .exe projectors running in the standalone Flash Player do not included these specific keyboard shortcuts, there will only be system specific keyboard shortcuts.